# WIndows API Code Pack

Tags: c#, windows-console

Is it possible to use functions from the Windows API Code Pack in a console application?  I would like to use the Jump list and icon  progress functions in a non-window console program.

Comment: I don't see why not. Did you read somewhere that you couldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  For an example (which is written in PowerShell, but uses the API pack), see:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/25/learn-how-to-use-powershell-to-configure-jump-lists.aspx